# HTML CSS hide all except last element

Tags: html, css

I'm tring to hide all elemnts inside a div except the last one, here is my html code:

```
<div id="TOPsession">
    <a id="link1" href="exc.txt">
        <img src="imagens/header/exc.png" align="center">
            <label id="label1">Label</label>
    </a>

    <a href="#" id="session">Session</a>
    <label id="lbar" style="color: #666;">|</label>
    <select id="sel"> 
        <option>German</option>
        <option>Ingles</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I searched on web and I find this css code to hide all except the last element:

```
#TOPsession:not(:last-child){
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

But this hide all the elements, someone know what im doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try `#TOPsession > :not(:last-child)`.

Comment: This doesn't do what you expect, this selector applies only when `#TOPsession` is that last child within its parent, this is not applying to last child elements within `#TOPSession`

Comment: @torazaburo thanks so much it works

Comment: @dippas how is this duplicated? are you kidding? first see the question and the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `#TOPsession > *:not(:last-child)`, this will select all direct children of `TOPsession` except `:last-child`.

---

If you don't use `>` you will also delete all elements inside last element except last element inside last element [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/798/)

```css
#TOPsession > *:not(:last-child) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="TOPsession">
  <a id="link1" href="exc.txt">
    <img src="imagens/header/exc.png" align="center">
    <label id="label1">Label</label>
  </a>

  <a href="#" id="session">Session</a>
  <label id="lbar" style="color: #666;">|</label>
  <select id="sel">
    <option>German</option>
    <option>Ingles</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: And it still could use an explanation (like my comment)

Comment: The `*` is not needed.